# Jacobian determinant of a map?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, determinant, differential

For $m,n\in \mathbb N$, let $f$ is the map given by 
$$\begin{align}
 f: & \quad \mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^n \\
& (x,y)\mapsto f(x,y) = (x+x',y+y'+[x,x']); \quad \mbox{for fixed } \, (x',y')\in \mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^n,  \end{align}$$
where $[.,.]$ is a map $[.,.] : \mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^m \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n.$

How to prove that the differential of $f$ is lower triangular, and thus the Jacobian determinant is $1$ (i.e., $|J_{f}|=1$) ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are the elements $(x',y')\in\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}n$ chosen? As such, this map does not seem to be well-defined.

Comment: the map $f$ is well-defined, because, in $(x+x',y+y'+[x,x'])$, we have $x+x'\in \mathbb R^m $ and as $[x,x'] \in \mathbb R^n$, $y+y'+[x,x']\in \mathbb R^n$, hence $(x+x',y+y'+[x,x']) \in \mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^n$

Comment: There are multiple ways in which a map can be ill-defined. Sure, since you state that $(x',y')$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$, the image is indeed contained in your codomain. However, as I asked explicitly, how are the elements $(x',y')$ chosen? As stated, this map is simply not defined completely, hence not well-defined.

Comment: we can see the maps $f$ is the  right-translation by an element $(x',y')$ in $\in\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: So it's a fixed, chosen element? You should make that clear.

Comment: Anyways, the Jacobian of a translation is the identity, and since you can view $f$ as the composition $(x,y)\to(x+x',y+y')\to(x+x',y+y'+[x,x')$, you need only consider the Jacobian of the second map, which is just the translation in the second component by the value of $[x,x']$.

Comment: ok, but why the differential of f$f$ is lower triangular ?

Comment: Have you tried calculating it using the definition, with the hint I gave you?

Comment: Ok, perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notational convenience, define the map
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^m&\longmapsto\mathbb{R}^n \\
(u,v)&\longmapsto[u,v].
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The map $f$ is a composition of the translation map
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n&\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n \\
(x,y)&\longmapsto(x+x',y+y')
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and the translation map
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T':\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n&\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n \\
(x,y)&\longmapsto(x,y+g(x,x')).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now the Jacobian matrix of a translation by a constant element is easily seen to be the identity, so we need only consider the Jacobian of $T'$. Since the map is non-trivial only in the "$\mathbb{R}^n$-part" of the map $T'$, and the map $g$ only depends on the first $m$ factors, the only non-zero entries of the Jacobian matrix are the diagonal and entries below the diagonal, so that the Jacobian is lower-triangular. As a simple example, if $T':\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^3$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$, then
\begin{equation}
DT'=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1} &\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_2} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_2} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{\partial g_3}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial g_3}{\partial x_2} & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
which is of course easily generalised for arbitrary $m$ and $n$.